# Appcelerator studio Titanium: Ti.Network.createCookie is not a function

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

this is my code:

```
Ti.Network.addHTTPCookie(Ti.Network.createCookie({
  path: currentCookie4,
  name: currentCookie2,
  value: currentCookie3,
  httponly: true,
}));
```

I got an error saying

```
Uncaught TypeError: Ti.Network.createCookie is not a function
```

For some reason Ti.Network.createCookie is undefined. Does anybody know why?

Comment: What platform are you building for?

Comment: Are you using LiveView?

Also check the values you are passing in the createCookie method.

I just checked your code by replacing your key's values by proper data type and it works fine.. no problem at all.